# Moving test theme to live site without mySQL error - how?

Tags: themes, redirect, mysql, import

I have installed a wordpress theme on a hidden test site and made some css/design changes.

How would I move this to my live site?

Sadly I screwed up some of the PHP/MySQL stuff when trying to copy posts from live site to test site database and there's a really hideous redirect loop thing going on.

Can I avoid copying that over, or am I really looking at having to start again with base theme and customisation from scratch?

Test site here:

`http://173.254.28.65/~neveren2/thundercatsaremyhomeboys/` - terrible redirect loop-

Live site:

http://www.neverenoughnotes.co.uk

Comment: Try by disabling your plugins one by one to find out which (if any) are causing the redirect loop

Answer (score 1):

Worst case scenario, just make a new environment, with that theme (can even be on the live), then just re-upload the CSS and anything else you've edited (successfully that is).